# Deploying Shield Platform Encryption using the CLI (force:madpi:deploy)

Tags: platform-encryption, shield

Can I enable encryption on custom object fields declaratively in an org, and then make successive deployments to that org from a codebase where `encryptionScheme` metadata is NOT part of the custom object metadata, AND do that without breaking the declaratively set encryption policy settings in the target org?  If it is possible to do it that way safely, I'd prefer that approach because I notice that once `encryptionScheme` metadata is in a local codebase, it creates several problems during subsequent deployments to scratch orgs and sandboxes that wouldn't otherwise occur.

A little background

1. Enabling encryption on custom object fields results in new custom object metadata after a `force:source:pull`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>My_Custom_Field__c</fullName>
    <encryptionScheme>CaseSensitiveDeterministicEncryption</encryptionScheme>
    <externalId>false</externalId>
    <label>My Custom Field</label>
    <length>255</length>
    <required>true</required>
    <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
    <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</CustomField>
```

2. I've been unable to `force:source:push`, `force:source:deploy`, or `force:mdapi:deploy` this metadata to scratch orgs or sandboxes successfully.  (And they've all had encryption enabled.) If I try, I encounter a wide variety of errors which I suspect are red-herrings for a more fundamental problem.

The errors range from

"Must specify a non-empty label for the CustomObject", to ...

"filters-criteriaItems-condition: Operators 'starts with', 'contains' and 'does not contain' do not work with the selected column"

Comment: can't speak for scratch orgs but for sandboxes; the target sandbox must have deterministic encryption enabled for the above XML to deploy